# Can you create the bolded "zero line" x=0 in ios-charts?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-charts

Does a `drawZeroLineEnabled` attribute exist in ios-charts for the mathematical line x=0 as well, or does the library just support the "zero" line y=0?

Comment: What exactly you want? you can put here what kind of graph you want to make.

Comment: I would like to make a bold line along the mathematical line x=0, specifically for interpreting the overall graph of a mathematical function more easily...